# Not able to find element of search box

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to write selenium code for a site. using java and testNG framework. i want to pass text in the search box, but not able to do it, some error occurred.

this is my code

```
public class Sele_test {
  @Test
  public void openUrl() throws InterruptedException {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\tools\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
      FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

      driver.get("http://www.testingexcellence.com/");

     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@placeholder='Search this website …' and @name='s']")).sendKeys("ss");
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<input itemprop="query-input" name="s" placeholder="Search this website …" type="search"><input value="Search" type="submit">
```

The error i am getting:

```
FAILED: openUrl
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'ADMIN', ip: '192.168.5.164', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\admin2\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.kjmLYGRcFu7v, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=6.3, moz:processID=5584, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: 1c4dcc01-dabb-40ed-892d-c9ab969ba11e
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:98)
    at java_class.Sele_test.openUrl(Sele_test.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: The ";;" at the end of driver.findElement it is a typo ?

Comment: yes i have edited.thanks. it was typo. with correct one, still there is error

Comment: what is the Firefox version that you are using; also selenium version?

Comment: from the stack trace it seems that sendKeys error, maybe your xpath is incorrect? could you please post html element that you need to do searching?

Comment: @kushal.   firefox 53.0  selenium 3.3.1

Comment: @adeealamsz  i have added html

Comment: Try downgrading firefox to v52; which just might work coz it is an ongoing issue with geckodriver; see here : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659

Comment: ok, the xpath looks fine, then try upgrading gecko driver to v0. 16 and  selenium to 3.4, it might solve your problem

Comment: Thanks.. @kushal. its working with chrome. so there is no issue with my code.

Comment: @disha I did had a look at "http://www.testingexcellence.com/" but unfortunately I didn't find a field "Search this website". What I found was the "Search" box provided by Mozilla Firefox. Additionally your correct xpath ".//*[@placeholder='Search this website …' and @name='s']" didn't fetch me any elements. Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this xpath for search box**

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='s']")).sendKeys("ss");

**it will work for sure..!!**

Answer (score -1):

I think the element attribute that you picked for you xpath is a bit tricky with dotted lines (probably is too long and it just displays the dots). Everything else looks good. Please try with this Xpath and let me know how it went (*notice how I slightly changed your xpath in the start*):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='search' and @name='s']")).sendKeys("ss");
```

Best of luck!